# Fixed Prices in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, fixed

I have a wordpress site with woocommerce installed, it is going to be a digital music store, and will have prices based on whether it is a single or mixtape. alot of people are going to be contributing to the site so it will be a nightmare if people enter the wrong price. does anyone know how to create:

1. dropdown with fixed price options
2. prices per product category
3. or possibly some sort of filter that wont allow the product to be posted unless it is an allowed amount.

i havent found a solution (or maybe i havent been searching in the right places) i have a vague understanding of php. any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the price via [`woocommerce_get_price`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L798).

An example:

```
function so_30998358_price( $price, $product ){
    if( has_term( 'expensive', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ){
        $price = 20;
    } else {
        $price = 10;
    }
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'so_30998358_price', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thank you for the repsponse, should i add it before or after "return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $this->price, $this ); "

Comment: No. Add it to your theme's functions.php or preferably make a site-specific plugin.

Comment: If this solves your problem, then please go ahead and accept this as the answer.

Comment: okay i ran into another problem. i have a plugin that allows the file to be download (replaces the add to cart button) if the regular price is equal to 0. but now when i add this code, and i put an else if with another category, it still returns the download button, but with the price displayed.

Comment: This merits a new question. But try to provide more info (like what plugin you are referring to) so that people can maybe answer.

Comment: sorry, i didnt explain that well. is it possible to create a input field that has options that a user can select, within the product-data section of 'add product' under the regular price label?. so where a user would type in the regular price, they can rather select 3 options